# Probability of at least once out of the three tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose a pair of fair dice is tossed 3 times. Let $X$ be the sum of the outcomes at each toss. Find the probability of getting a sum of 7 (i.e., $X=7$) at least once out of the three tosses.

My attempt:

The sample space is $6^3=216.$ There are 15 combinations that gives a sum of $7$.

$$P(X=7)=\frac{15}{216}$$

I am stuck here. If a pair of fair dice is tossed 3 times, should the sample space be 36 or 216? Am I on the right path?

Comment: You have to show how you worked out $\frac{15}{216}$. The method you used could have a problem , or it could be a calculation : either way, showing it would make life easier for somebody trying to answer your question. Did you enumerate the possibilities, or notice any independence etc.?

Comment: Hint: find the probability of the complement of that event, i.e. the probability that a sum $7$ does not arise at the $3$ tosses.

Comment: Your result $15/216$ accords with the probability that the sum of *three* dice rolled *once* (or one die rolled three times) will be $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Bernouly process. The probability that you get 7 at one toss is $$p={6\over 36}={1\over 6}$$

So not getting 7 in 3 trials is $$P' = q^3 = (1-p)^3 = {125\over 216}$$

So the finaly answer is $$ P = 1-P' ={91\over 216}$$

Answer (score 1):

let X = getting total of 7 then sample space S={(1,6)(6,1)(2,5)(5,2)(3,4)(4,3)}=6 times
Total number of outcomes =
{(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)
 (2,1).....................(2,6)
 (3,1).....................(3,6)
 (4,1)
 (5,1) 
 (6,1),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,(6,6)}=6x6=36 outcomes
P(getting total 7)=p(x)=6/36=1/6
q=5/6

getting 7 atleast once 
p(x>=1)=1-p(x<1)
=1-p(x=0)
=1- ncx p^x q^n-x  , n=3 p =1/6 q=5/6
=1- [3c0 (1/6)^0 (5/6)^3-0]
=0.42

Comment: Please use MathJax.